# How to create announcement channel

Tags: discord, discord.js, channel

I'm trying to create an announcement channel, but it just creates another text channel. This is my code

```
guild.channels.create("test", {
   type: "announcement",
   parent: cate,
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no channel with "announcement" Type
[Channel#type](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel?scrollTo=type)

Replace announcement with "news"

```js
guild.channels.create("test", {
   type: "news"
})
```